# In the PHP runtime environment for Google App Engine, how can I write unit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, google-app-engine, phpunit

I have a set of [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) tests for an application that I am porting to App Engine. I'd like to get these running. But I'd be interested in seeing any examples of unit tests for the PHP runtime. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/) is mum and [my searches](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=app+engine+php+unit+testing) have been futile.

In this particular case, I'd be looking to mock out parts of the [User API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/users/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My PHP-GDS library for app engine has a set of unit tests.

Feel free to take a look!

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

I take advantage of a mock Protocol Buffer function to simulate responses from the Google services.

Also a smaller set of unit tests are here

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-search

One of the key things in the inclusion of the SDK

google/appengine-php-sdk

Hope this helps!

Tom